# Docker Image java library information

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-image

I have a custom docker image. I need to check what all java dependency that image using. Is there any way to find out?
Please help.

Comment: A Docker image isn't guaranteed to be running a Java program or to have any of the tools you'd need to find this out.  It'd be easier to run something like `./gradlew dependencies` on the original source tree, before you build an image out of it.

Comment: Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)how to ask a good question. Your question is currently missing too much information to be able to help you